# Inverse action of Thread

Tags: list-manipulation

I cannot find the original post now, but I'm quite sure that there's an amazing post teaching us how to do `Thread` on ragged lists.

But my problem is **how to inverse this action?**

For example, you can use this customized version of `Thread`:

```
MyThread[l1_,l2_]=If[Length@l1==Length@l2!=0,MapThread[MyThread, {l1, l2}],{l1,l2}]

MyThread[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{5, {3, 4}}, {6, {4, 5}}}}
> ```

But now I get the result and would like to reverse it into two lists(of course you can change it to a thread of 3 or more). The key I think is that at some part of the structure there'll be only two element and that'll be the place to seperate.

Also, If this is too difficult or impossible theoretically, I have another simplified version:

I know that at the bottom level there's only two element while the latter one is an atom expression. e.g. `{{{1, 2}, False}, {{2, False}, {3, False}}, {{5, False}, {6, True}}}`

**How to make this back to its original form?**

The desired result will be:
`{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}},{False,{False,False},{False,True}}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list={{{1,2},{1}},{{2,2},{3,3}},{{5,{3,4}},{6,{4,5}}}};    
Transpose[If[Quiet[Check[Transpose[#],True]]===True,#,Transpose[#]]&/@list]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}}}

Comment: OMG, That is awesome!